# How to get a list with all branches and the latest tag that includes a number in Git?

Tags: git

I have many Git branches containing different version tags. I am looking for a solution, where I get a list of all my branches and their latest numbered tag line by line. (Versioning has always the same format: X.Y.Z)

Example:

master  : 2.2.2

branchB : 2.2.1

branchC : 2.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have any unwanted tags littering up the place @sajibkhan's got the right idea,

```
git for-each-ref refs/heads refs/remotes --format='
        printf '%s: ' %(refname:short); git describe --tags --abbrev=0 %(refname:short)
' |sh
```

or with a more familiar `while read`,

```
git branch -a|sed s/.//|while read branch; do
        printf '%s: ' "$branch"; git describe --tags --abbrev=0 $branch
done
```

but your

> their latest numbered tag

makes me think you've got some tags that aren't numbered, and those would make the `git describe` give wrong results sometimes.

---

`git describe` has a `--match` option, so if you can cook up a positive-match glob for the tags you want to consider, e.g. if `--match=[0-9]*` will do it, just add that.  But e.g. linux has tags like `v4.8.1` and `v2.6.3-rc7`, and matching just the first with a glob pattern ain't easy.

For situations like that, there's a really good technique for ref surgery:

```
scratch=`mktemp -d`
git clone -s --mirror . "$scratch"
cd !$
```

makes a really quick scratch clone with duplicated refs but no actual content. The `-s` is short for `--shared`, the repo uses the main object db, and mirrored clones are always bare so there's no checkout.  Use shared-object clones for any temporary work where you're really unsure you'll want the results, or you want before-and-afters.

So now that you're in your sandboxed mirror, you can just delete the refs you don't want to see here:

```
git for-each-ref refs/tags/*[^0-9.]* --format='
        delete %(refname)
' | git update-ref --stdin
```

deletes every tag that has a non-digit-or-dot in its name anywhere.

And the cleaned-up scratch-monkey refname space is ready for the straightforward `git describe`s above.

---

This is a general technique: you can push and fetch any refs you want, anywhere with a url or pathname, with any kind of rewriting you want.  This includes your local repo.  Here, for instance, is the brutal way to make or fast-forward local branches for every remote-tracking branch:

```
git fetch . refs/remotes/origin/*:refs/heads/*
```

(do that in a scratch clone first...)

Comment: Thanks! Looks really good. I get only one error: cd: !$: No such file or directory.

Comment: The `!$` is history-expansion syntax, if your shell doesn't have it turned on type the last argument from the previous command line instead i.e. `"$scratch"`

Comment: Sorry, still not working. I put all lines in a bash file and get fatal: Not a valid object name s. Seems all works until git describe s. I tried to learn more about -s option, but I could not solve it.

Comment: Could you give a little more detail here?  Run the command with `sh -x your-bash-file.sh` and post the results.

Comment: Your're misreading "`git describe`s above", it's referring to the `git describe` examples I gave earlier, either of the three-liners at the top.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is exactly what you want -

```
git branch -a | while read branch; do
    echo "$branch"; git describe --tags --abbrev=0 $branch
done
```

It shows `all local & remote branches with latest tag`.

Sample Output:

```
* master 
0.3
branch-1
0.2.1
remotes/origin/master 
0.3
```

Comment: This is the right idea but gives the wrong output in a lot of circumstances. Could you fix it up some?

Comment: @jthill I added sample output. Can you give me an example in which circumstances showing wrong output, then I can check it?

Comment: Thanks, but that outputs to me all branches with the latest tag (not numbered) including branches that don't even have the tag. I found out I could use somehing like --match 2.*. But still the listing is wrong for me.

Comment: @jthill I've updated my answer. Now it seems to be working.